# Angular 2 NGRX: who initializes the routers?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I built a router following the example from the [NGRX example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app), the layout router to be precise. The new code looks like this:

AppComponent:

```
import * as fromRoot from '../../reducers';
import * as uiActions from '../../actions/ui-actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
  <div #wrapper>
    <div>
      <app-header (toggleFullscreen$)="toggleFullscreen()"></app-header>
    </div>
  </div>
 `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper: ElementRef;
  isFullScreen$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>){
    this.isFullScreen$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getFullscreenMode);
  }

  isFullscreenAvailable(): boolean { ...
  }

  toggleFullscreen() {
    if (!this.isFullScreen$.last){
      if (this.isFullscreenAvailable) {
        this.store.dispatch(new uiActions.EnableFullscreen());
      }
    } else {
      this.store.dispatch(new uiActions.DisableFullscreen());
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.isFullScreen$.subscribe((isFullscreen: boolean) => {...}
  }
```

UiReducer:

```
import * as uiActions from "../actions/ui-actions";

export interface State {
  fullscreen: boolean;
}

const INITIAL_UI_STATE: State = {
  fullscreen: false
};

export function reducer(state: State = INITIAL_UI_STATE, action: uiActions.Actions): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case uiActions.ActionTypes.ENABLE_FULLSCREEN: {
      return {
        fullscreen:true
      }
    }
    case uiActions.ActionTypes.DISABLE_FULLSCREEN: {
      return {
        fullscreen:false
      }
    }
    default: {
      console.log("default state: "+ JSON.stringify(state));
      return state;
    }
  }
}

export const getFullscreenMode = (state: State) => {
  console.log("state from reducer method : " + state)
  return state.fullscreen;
}
```

inside index.ts of router directory:

```
export const getUiState = (state: State) => state.uiState;
export const getFullscreenMode = createSelector(getUiState, fromUi.getFullscreenMode);
```

yet I get errors when I launch the app and I do not know how to trace them back. The console says:

```
ui-reducer.ts:24 default state: {"fullscreen":false}
ui-reducer.ts:24 default state: {"fullscreen":false}
ui-reducer.ts:31 state from reducer method : undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullscreen' of undefined ...
state from reducer method : undefined
zone.js:569 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'fullscreen' of undefined
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullscreen' of undefined
```

As I said, I have no clue how to debug this. What calls the router originally, when its stream is not initialized yet? Is there some background process? It seems it tries to access the store variables before they are initialized. Why does this code not work for me when it looks exactly the same in the example application?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else encountering this issue, the problem was not in the code that I posted but having different variable names in

```
export interface State {
  layoutState: fromLayout.State;
}

const reducers = {
  layoutReducer: fromLayout.reducer,
};
```

in this case layoutState and layoutReducer must be called the same because the selector refers to the reducer, while the compiler shows the state as the referred object, causing a lot of confusion